# Derived Classes Error

Tags: c++, class, derived-class

I finished a small program using derived classes and it compiles correctly, but the output is wrong.

The program uses an ordered pair (x, y) as the center for a circle. It then uses the center and the radius given to determine the area and circumference of the circle.

Outputting ordered pairs with the pointType class works fine, but when I tested the circleType class I expected to get (0, 0) as a default. Instead I got (2293512, 2293700)

Any help given will be appreciated!

Here's the point class code:

```
#ifndef POINTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#define POINTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>

class pointType{
 public:
  pointType (int=0, int=0);
  int getX() const;
  int getY() const;
  void setX(int);
  void setY(int);
  void setValues(int, int);
  friend pointType operator + (pointType, pointType);
  friend pointType operator - (pointType, pointType);
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, pointType);
 private:
  int x;
  int y;
};

#endif // POINTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
```

Here's the point class implementation:

```
#include "pointType.h"

pointType::pointType (int X, int Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}

int pointType::getX () const {
 return x;
}

int pointType::getY () const {
 return y;
}

void pointType::setX (int new_x) {
 x = new_x;
}

void pointType::setY (int new_y) {
 y = new_y;
}

void pointType::setValues (int new_x, int new_y) {
 x = new_x;
 y = new_y;
}

pointType operator + (pointType lh, pointType rh){
 pointType answer;

 answer.x = lh.x + rh.x;
 answer.y = lh.y + rh.y;

 return answer;
}

pointType operator - (pointType lh, pointType rh){
 pointType answer;

 answer.x = lh.x - rh.x;
 answer.y = lh.y - rh.y;

 return answer;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, pointType c){
 out << "(" << c.x << ", " << c.y << ")";
 return out;
}
```

Here's the circle class:

```
#ifndef CIRCLETYPE_H_INCLUDED
#define CIRCLETYPE_H_INCLUDED
#include "pointType.h"
#include <iostream>

class circleType: protected pointType {
 public:
  circleType (float=0);
  circleType (int=0, int=0);
  void setRadius (float);
  float calculateArea (float);
  float calculateCircumference (float);
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, circleType);
 private:
  float radius;
  int center_x;
  int center_y;
};

#endif // CIRCLETYPE_H_INCLUDED
```

Here's the circle class implementation:

```
#include "pointType.h"
#include "circleType.h"
#include <math.h>

const float PI = 3.14;

circleType::circleType(float R): radius(R) {}

circleType::circleType(int center_X, int center_Y):
 pointType(center_x, center_y) {}

void circleType::setRadius(float new_radius) {
 radius = new_radius;
}

float circleType::calculateArea(float radius) {
 float area;
 area = PI * pow(radius, 2);
 return area;
}

float circleType::calculateCircumference(float radius) {
 float circumference;
 circumference = PI * (radius * 2);
 return circumference;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& odata, circleType f) {
 odata << "(" << f.center_x << ", " << f.center_y << ")";
 return odata;
}
```

Here's the testing code:

```
#include "pointType.h"
#include "circleType.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  pointType c, d(8, 9);
  circleType f(4, 5);
  cout << c << endl;
  cout << d << endl;
  c.setValues(12, 3);
  cout << c << endl;

  cout << c + d << endl;
  cout << c - d << endl;

  cout << f << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm semi annoyed that `circleType` even compiles, considering you don't have an unambiguous default constructor.  (Both constructors are callable as `circleType()`.  You should pick one as the default constructor, and lose at least one of the optional arguments in the other.)

Comment: what do you mean by optional arguments?

Comment: Btw: Pass arguments in operators by reference, e.g: `Foo& operator+(const Foo& rhs);`

Comment: The `int = 0` arguments are optional; if you omit them when calling, a 0 gets put there by the compiler.  In `circleType`'s case, though, both constructors have all optional args, making them both callable as the default constructor `circleType()`.  If i were to say `circleType c;`, the compiler wouldn't know which constructor to call.

Comment: By the way...and i'm not sure how many people will agree with this, but...the point of a constructor is to turn an array of bytes into a usable object.  That means without a very, *very* good reason, it-- along with super/subclass constructors -- should put the entire object into a known valid state, including giving all data members known and usable (if not useful) values.  For example, `circleType::circleType(int, int)` should be setting `radius`...say, to 0.  If you don't, they could have any value -- or in some cases, no value at all, or a value that causes the app to crash, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the circleType int members center_x and center_y are never set. Your constructor CircleType::CircleType(int=0,int=0) calls the base constructor, which in turn set pointType.x and pointType.y, both private members of the base class (and hence not available to circleType).

My suggestion (or what I think you intended\expected): make int x and int y protected, not private, and remove center_x and center_y, then print odata << "(" << f.x << ", " << f.y << ")";

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, but I would rather keep x and y as private if I can.

Comment: Remove center_x (+y) and use your getters and setters instead to access x (+y) in the child class

Answer (score 0):

Its a typo.

```
circleType::circleType(int center_X, int center_Y):
pointType(center_x, center_y) {}
```

Notice the difference between center_**X** (uppercase) and center_**x** (lowercase).
You pass your uninitialized members to the parent constructor which can have any value lingering at the stack.

Therefor it is good practive to always preceed your members with `m_` e.g: `m_centerX`. (In this particular case it isnt even neccessary to have them again in the child class, redundancy is bad!)

EDIT:

Sorry for the confusion, but please be more precisly next time, could have saved us all alot of time. I assumed that your problems occurs when adding a point with a circle, after running the code by my own I noticed that it happens when outputting f. The reason is the same as explained above: you dont initialize your members! They simply hold any value which were currently at the memory location the object becomes constructed.

Comment: fixed the typos, but it didn't change the output

Comment: do you pass `center_X` (uppercase, parameter in the constructor) to the parent constructor now?

Comment: i changed it from pointType (center_x, center_y) {} to pointType (center_X, center_Y) if that answers your question

Comment: Hm odd, I was almost sure that this was the problem :(

Comment: Apparently I have problems with initializing my variables as I've gotten similar comments on previous programs. What do you mean by that?

Comment: It means that `int someMember;` has no specific / a random value unless you initialize / set it. You do this by passing it a value in the initializer list: `Foo::Foo(int someParam) : someMember(someParam) {...}`. But be relieved that even expirienced programmers forget this, I think its due to RAII why people have problems with it because objects become automatically initialized (using the default constructor).

Answer (score 0):

In your circleType class, center_x and center_y aren't being initialised. The parameters are being passed directly to the pointType constructor and setting the private members. You can prove this by changing the operator<< function that takes a circleType argument:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& odata, circleType f) {
    odata << "(" << f.center_x << ", " << f.center_y << ")" << std::endl;
    odata << "(" << f.getX() << ", " << f.getY() << ")"; //access superclass
    return odata;
}
```

With protected inheritance, you also can't use the + and - overloads defined for the base class either, it won't compile.